# Alternative to Dropbox public folder for navigatable links

Tags: dropbox, cloud-storage

I am an iOS developer and, until recently, had been using Dropbox's public folder as a makeshift server for testing purposes. This is because public folders had static URLs and the subfolders and files they contain could be accessed directly though the file tree (ex: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/xxxxxxx/audioTests/). This was useful when iterating through a variable array of files, as I could just specify the folder url and append the individual file names (ex: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/xxxxxxx/audioTests/music.mp3).

As of this month, however, dropbox has discontinued this feature for free users and is planning to remove it for paid users later this year. Does anyone know of a (preferably free) alternative that offers this same kind of navigatable public folder? I need a minimal amount of space, as I will just be using it for testing purposes. All of the other similar services that I know of, such as Google Drive and OneDrive, only offer links to individual files and folders.

Comment: Question asking for recommendations is not good on SO. Anyway, some suggestions are Netlify, Firebase and GitHub pages.